# How to print Multiple polygons in for loop with matplotlib

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib

I want to print some polygons (pentagon) as an image. I made an array of (4,5,2) which are the coordinates of 4 pentagon. I want the code to print 4 pentagon in a for loop. The issue is that my code prints just one polygon in each run. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

my_dpi = 100

coord = np.array([[[-150, -200], [300, -200], [300, 0], [150, 200], [-150, 200]],
                  [[-110, -220], [340, -250], [280, 0], [120, 200], [-140, 210]],
                  [[-140, -230], [350, -260], [350, 0], [140, 200], [-180, 220]],
                  [[-180, -240], [370, -270], [370, 0], [170, 200], [-190, 230]]])

for i in range(4):
    i = 0
    geo = coord[i, :, :]

print(coord[i])

polygon = plt.Polygon(coord[i], color='w')
plt.gca().add_patch(polygon)
plt.savefig('figure/%d.jpg' % i, dpi=my_dpi)
i =+ 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem was the `print` statement was outside of the `for` loop, so it was only printing the last set of coordinates. I also removed the `i=0` line so it printed correctly. The code below prints all of the coordinates.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

my_dpi = 100

coord = np.array([[[-150, -200], [300, -200], [300, 0], [150, 200], [-150, 200]],
                  [[-110, -220], [340, -250], [280, 0], [120, 200], [-140, 210]],
                  [[-140, -230], [350, -260], [350, 0], [140, 200], [-180, 220]],
                  [[-180, -240], [370, -270], [370, 0], [170, 200], [-190, 230]]])

for i in range(4):
    geo = coord[i, :, :]
    print(coord[i])

polygon = plt.Polygon(coord[i], color='w')
plt.gca().add_patch(polygon)
plt.savefig('figure/%d.jpg' % i, dpi=my_dpi)
i =+ 1
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed a code little bit to save 4 pentagons as image at each step but it save the second image on the first image and third on the second and so on. I need each image include one separate polygon.

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pixels = 600
my_dpi = 100
num_geo=3

coord = np.array([[[-150, -200], [300, -200], [300, 0], [150, 200], [-150, 200]],
                  [[-300, -200], [200, -300], [200, -50], [200, 300], [-150, 200]],
                  [[-140, -230], [350, -260], [350, 0], [140, 200], [-180, 220]],
                  [[-180, -240], [370, -270], [370, 0], [170, 200], [-190, 230]]])


fig = plt.figure(num_geo,figsize=( pixels/my_dpi,  pixels/my_dpi),facecolor='k', dpi=my_dpi)  


plt.axes([0,0,1,1])

rectangle = plt.Rectangle((-300, -300), 600, 600, fc='k')
plt.gca().add_patch(rectangle)



for i in range(4):

    geo = coord[i, :, :]
    print(coord[i])

    polygon = plt.Polygon(coord[i],color='w')
    plt.gca().add_patch(polygon)
    plt.savefig('figure/%d.jpg' % i, dpi=my_dpi)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.axis([-300,300,-300,300])
i =+ 1
```